# Pybind11 ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import modules across different files

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, modulenotfounderror

Disclaimer, I have just started using Pybind11 and do not have much experience with C++. I've had success in using Pybind until I've needed to add inheritance. I am able to successfully generate a shared object file (e.g. *derived_class.so*), but get an error when trying to include it in my python project:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_class'`

I was trying to follow along with the docs, [specifically the portion that talks about partitioning modules across multiple files](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#partitioning-code-over-multiple-extension-modules)

Below I've included a stripped down version to orchestrate what I'm working with and attempting to accomplish.

**C++ Classes**

```cpp
// base_class.h
class BaseClass {
    public:
        BaseClass(int id): id(int id) {}
        int get_id() { return id; }
    private:
        int id;
}
```

```cpp
// derived_class.h
#include "common/base_class"

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass {
    public:
        DerivedClass(int id);
}
```

```cpp
// derived_class.cpp
#include "derived_class.h"

DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int id): BaseClass(id) {}
```

**C++ Bindings**

```cpp
// base_class_binding.cpp

#include "base_class.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(base_class, m) {
    py::class_<BaseClass>(m, "BaseClass")
        .def(py::init<int>());
}
```

```cpp
// derived_class_binding.cpp

#include "common/base_class.h"
#include "derived_class.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(derived_class, m) {
    //attempt to import module as per docs
    py::module_::import("base_class");
    
    // use of imported module class as per docs
    py::class_<DerivedClass, BaseClass>(m, "DerivedClass")
        .def(py::init<int>());
}
```

**Library Generation**

```
g++ -std=c++20 -shared -fpic `python3.12 -m pybind11 --includes` derived_class.cpp derived_class_binding.cpp common/base_class_binding.cpp -o derived_class.so
```

**Python usage**

```py
# test.py
from derived_class import DerivedClass # THIS GENERATES EXCEPTION

if __name__ == '__main__':
    derivedClass = DerivedClass(1)
    print(f'The ID is: {derivedClass.get_id()}')
```

I'm expecting my library to import, and then utilize the `get_id()` function of the base class. I've tried various combinations of:

- The alternate approach to import a module (py::object).
- Including the *base_class_binding.cpp* into *derived_class_binding.cpp* directly (as opposed to using the module import.
- Defining a new `py::class_<BaseClass>` within *derived_class_binding.cpp*, which works, but defeats the purpose of having modules escapsulated per file. It also means I need to redeclare it for all of the other files that use it.